# Html ActionLink Route problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have defined the following Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog",
            "Blog/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

When i call http://localhost/ all Links are wrong and go to the Blog:

@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") creates the following URL:

localhost/Blog/About

but it should create

localhost/About

Why does HtmlActionLink always prefix the urls with the "Blog"?

Answer (score 1):

`ActionLink` will the first route that matches the parameters you passed to it.
Since your `Blog` route contains the `controller` and `action` parameters, it will use that route.

You should change your `Blog` route to be more specific.

Comment: What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: I can't make the blog route more specific. It will be handled like an area. "Blog" ist just the prefix

Comment: @David: Then you should use an area.  Having multiple ambiguous routes like this will lead to trouble.