# @Html.ActionLink helper pointing to current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

### Setup:

I am using the `Html.ActionLink` helper to create a tags to my action, `Reset`, in the controller `PasswordReset`, in the area `Admin`.

### Html.ActionLink calls (EDITED, but still no joy):

The calls to Html.ActionLink are in a foreach loop (html simplified):

```
foreach(var item in Model.Entities)
{
   <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", 
          "Reset",
          "PasswordReset", 
          new {area="Admin", 
               userName=item.UserName, 
               email=item.Email, 
               roles=item.Roles},
          null)
   </p>
}
```

### My action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult Reset(string userName, string email, string roles)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Username!");
            var ue = new UsernameEmailDTO
            {
                UserName = userName,
                Email = email,
                Roles = roles
            };
            return View(ue);
        }
```

### Route:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_PasswordReset",
            "Admin/Password/Reset/{userName}",
            new { controller = "PasswordReset", action="Reset", email = UrlParameter.Optional, roles = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

### Problem:

I can call the action directly using the route.

However, my action link just produces a link that points to the current page.

So there has to be an error in my Html.ActionLink code.

But what?!

Very frustrating as I thought I was over this variety of pain barrier.

Comment: Shooting from the hip, but try moving the controller property out of the routeValues and into its native parameter of the ActionLink helper.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble:  Nope, doesn't work either.  I have however amended the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Could you post the link produced by the Html.ActionLink?

Comment: As stated in the question, it just produces a link that points to the current page.  No point posting that.

Comment: Well just trying to help you! Maybe something is messed up by Areas configuration! Maybe Html.RouteLink solves the problem. Take a look here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432185/html-actionlink-between-areas

Comment: Thanks your effort, Fals.  Sorry if I have been snappy about you guessing.  I'm call it a day.

Comment: Have you tried Haack's Route Debugger? http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The helper is overridding your url with the current route path. Pass routeValues: null as parameter to resolve this issue.

```
foreach(var item in Model.Entities)
{
    <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "Reset", "PasswordReset", 
     new {
            userName = item.UserName,
            email = item.Email,
        roles = item.Roles }
    )
    </p>
}
```

EDIT: I see this now. The problem is your route config. You are passing 3 parameters, but your routes take only one. When Html helper creates the route, its take the first route that matches.

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_PasswordReset",
        "Admin/Password/Reset/{userName}/{email}/{roles}",
        new { controller = "PasswordReset", action="Reset", email = UrlParameter.Optional, roles = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Found it here: [Html ActionLink Route problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923107/html-actionlink-route-problem)

Comment: you can't set routeValues to null - I need that!  Did you mean htmlAttributes = null?  Also, as written, your code produces an error: named parameters can't go before positional ones.

Comment: I did some research try this and let me know! :)

Comment: there is no reason for it work if my route doesn't:  the other two parameters are optional.  As in UrlParameter.Optional.  I tried it and as expected, it doesn't work.